# React Native App not navigating after successful firebase auth

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using expo to build my first react native app, so far been great and I am only frustrated with one issue:

My app is not redirecting to "profile" after successful login. Here is how I handle login/signup using firebase:

```
class Login extends React.Component {

state = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
}

handleLogin = () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state
         Firebase.auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) 
        .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile'))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>traderank</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputBox}
                value={this.state.email}
                onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                placeholder='email'
                autoCapitalize='none'
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputBox}
                value={this.state.password}
                onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                placeholder='password'
                secureTextEntry={true}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this.handleLogin}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <Button 
            title="no account? sign up" 
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup')}/>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

Signup is the same with this handleAuth function:

```
handleSignUp = () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state
    Firebase.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile'))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

1)I know it is not a problem with my navigator, because I can go between login/signup by clicking buttons.

2)I know it is not a problem with firebase, because I can create a new user and see the user in the firebase console

3)I am getting this error when I click login:

> Error: Failed to create storage directory.Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “RCTAsyncLocalStorage” doesn’t exist."

> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/264989F0-2165-4E91-8EA3-48316590DE5A/data/Containers/Data/Application/A49D7AF5-C660-4292-9576-A986C3F97C38/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%40anonymous%project-numbers/RCTAsyncLocalStorage, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000778180

> {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

It should redirect when I click Signup too, but when I create a new user I see this get logged in my terminal [User is being created when I click signup, I see user in firebase console]:

> Failed to create storage directory.Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “RCTAsyncLocalStorage” doesn’t exist."

It seems to be an issue with RCTAsyncLocalStorage in both instances. Normally I can google the error and figure it out, but haven't found much on this. I am using react native expo ~39.0.2, running it on an iPhone 11 (13.7).

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the test of your login screen?

Comment: Sure, will update once I’m home!

Comment: @WenW updated with full login

Comment: my login screen looks fine. Are you conditionally rendering the profile page in your navigator? Similar to what's being done here? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Comment: @WenW No conditional rendering yet. Should I do it that way?

Comment: @WenW its just a basic stack navigator

Comment: are you storing the UseInfo data anywhere in your app?

Comment: @WenW. Nope. My app is literally user, signup and a profile Page.  Signup looks almost identical to login, and I just want the profile page to show when successful login and signup happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error happened because of a problem in your simulator,
Try to change it or use another mobile and run the app on it.

There was an issue related to your problem,
You can check it from [here](https://github.com/DiscipleTools/disciple-tools-mobile-app/issues/17)

Comment: Great! I changed the simulator to do a different device and it worked - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the same error happened to me, and indeed the problem was with the iOS emulator, to solve it I simply went to the device option and erase all the data and content of the emulator. with this the problem was solved